# Looping through posts with puppeteer and capturing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have set up puppeteer on my facebook marketplace profile. Ultimately, I want puppeteer to open up every item I have listed and then capture the data for the name, price, date posted, description, views, and then push this information to an array. Too problems are stumping me. The first is the code I created to open the item's description is currently only opening the first item for every item I have listed. How can I dynamically change the index number to loop through the other items as well? Here is my code:

```
const moreDataClick = async (page) => {
      let moreDataTrue = await page.evaluate(() => {
          let furtherDataButtons = document.querySelectorAll(`span[title]`);
          if(furtherDataButtons.length) {
              let furtherDataButton = furtherDataButtons[num];
              furtherDataButton.click();

              return true;
          }
          return false;
      });
      if (moreDataTrue) {
        await page.waitForSelector("button._3-9a._50zy._50-1._50z_._5upp._42ft");
        await page.waitFor(5000)
        await page.evaluate(() =>{
          document.querySelector('button._3-9a._50zy._50-1._50z_._5upp._42ft').click();            
        });
    }
    await page.waitForFunction(`document.querySelectorAll('button._3-9a._50zy._50-1._50z_._5upp._42ft').length==0`);
    }

    await scrapeInfiniteScrollItems(page, 100);

    console.log("scrolldown done...");


    let moreDataButtonCounts = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('span[title]').length);

    console.log("moreDataButtonsCount", moreDataButtonCounts);

    for(let i = 0; i < moreDataButtonCounts; i++) {
      await moreDataClick(page);
  }
```

My second issue is I am unsure how to capture the data, exit the item's popup, then move on to the next item and capture it's data etc. I am unsure where to put this code to capture the data, and unsure how to access the array at the end of my code when the data capture does not all occur at once. Here is the code I would like to insert:

```
   var facebookPostData = await page.evaluate(() => {
     var title = document.querySelector('span[data-testid="marketplace_pdp_title"]').innerText;
     var price = document.querySelector('._5_md._2iel').innerText;
     var viewed = document.querySelector('._43kf._50f8').innerText.replace(/\D+/g, '');
     var datePosted = document.querySelector('a._r3j[title]').title;
     var description = document.querySelector('p._4etw').innerText;

     var titleArray = [];

       titleArray.push({
         title: title,
         price: price,
         views: viewed,
         date: datePosted,
         desc: description
       });

     return titleArray;
     console.log(titleArray);
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i were you i would explain my code a bit , keep in mind we're not familiar with facebook html structure and have no idea what  your code does by just looking at it ... so here's an generic answer

```
// capture all the items
let elements = await page.$$('.item');
// loop trough items
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    // if you need to capture element and/or its text inside item
    let  data_elemtn  =  await elements[i].$('.item-data');
    let  data_elemtn_text = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, data_elemtn);

    // capture and click the popup button
    let  button  =  await elements[i].$('.popup-button');
    await button.click();

    // wait for the popup to show up
    await page.waitForSelector('.popup-element' , {  visible: true , timeout: 0 });

    // capture data inside popup and close it

}
```